# Bilateral Filter of an Intensity/Time Signal with Tiny Spatial Values

Tags: python, time-series, filtering, signal-processing, convolution

I'm new to StackOverflow so forgive me if my posting style isn't quite robust enough. Still learning lol. Also still relatively inexperienced/new to more advanced forms of preprocessing. I tried wording this my best, but I don't have all the terms down either, so if there's anything I got wrong terminology wise please let me know so I don't come off wrong in the future.

So for context I'm working on filtering several sequences of values where each sequence is in the neighborhood of 250000 observations. Each feature vector has excess noise that is an impulse-style spike. Think like a series of Seismographs, kind of.

Frequency is in seconds with 0.00625 seconds per observation.

I am attempting to denoise via Bilateral Filter. It has to be Bilateral in this instance, though, and it also has to be in Python.

But the values are very small.
This is an example of the DF with time intensity values together.
[This is a sample of what part of a sequence would look like (approx 5000 points)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBDs9.png)

[Here is what the data looks like as a DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMVfB.png)

The first half of my question is basically how to handle this since the step in Proximity is soooo small, and since the intensity values that would affect the range kernel are so small? I thought about using a number based off of the signal variance as a sigma_r. However that variance will most likely be in the ten thousandths place if not further. Additionally I considered using an upper quartile or maybe the median of scipy's peak_widths function for a sigma_s. But when I think about it the values seem so tiny I'm doubtful it'd work super well either. If push comes to shove though it's pretty much the best approach I've been able to think up, but I'm just rather doubtful it's the best way of finding the spatial sigma.

As for the second half of my question, I'm going to be attempting this in numba to try and get *some* of the speed efficiency back there. But y'know I still understand this is going to take a long time to process. I'm working from a pretty beaten up laptop, so my second request is just for general best practices on memory management when manipulating such large amounts of data. For instance, should I vectorize or not going with this approach? An example of this kind of management was simply to reduce data size for testing purposes, I've decided to slice the data to what you see in the lineplot to keep computation time efficient while I figure out a reasonable approach.
I've never had to do that before, so it didn't occur to me right away to try it. (I don't want to ask for too much specific code really, as I really want to improve my skills translating symbolic equations into code by stepping through them mathwise. *Unless* I'm told that I smoothbrained it and come crawling back of course )

Regardless, I would appreciate any input y'all have!

P.S. It has to be a BF, unfortunately. No FFT denoising or SVD with rank cutoffs :(
P.P.S. My doubt primarily stems from issues that arise when small, near 0 values are subtracted from each other or divided and bottom to 0 or have unreliably high error when dividing etc... If that seems unfounded here then please let me know!

Thank you again, honestly